# React html2canvas jspdf Multiple Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas, react-pdf

I am hoping to use html2canvas and jspdf to download a multi page PDF.

I can do single pages no problem with the following:

```
  printDocument = () => {
const input = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
html2canvas(input, {scale: 4,})
  .then((canvas) => {
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4', true);

    var width = (pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() * 0.90);
    var height = (pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() * 0.90);


    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, width, height, '','FAST');
    // pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');

    pdf.save("download.pdf");

  });
```

I also know I can add a page with the following:

```
pdf.addPage();
```

If I had a three page document split into 3 divs `<div id="divToPrint1"> ... </div>, <div id="divToPrint2"> ... </div>, and <div id="divToPrint3"> ... </div>` how would I create and download all 3 pages together.

Any help is greatly appreciated!